# $L_y$ in terms of $L_+$ and $L_-$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

On the 5th slide of http://web.ift.uib.no/~lipniack/phys201_v08/angularmomentum.pdf, they say that:
$$L_y=\frac{i}{2}(L_+-L-)$$
And this is not the only place I have seen this (http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node247.html for instance use this implicitly). However, if I start with $L_{\pm}=L_x\pm i L_y$ and then do $L_+-L_-$ I get:
$$L_+-L_-=2iL_y$$
$$L_y=\frac{1}{2i}(L_+-L-)$$
So where do they get the formula:

$$L_y=\frac{i}{2}(L_+-L-)$$
from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, they are mistaken.
You can verify this by noticing that (Using their $L_y$):
$$L_+=L_x+iL_y=\frac{1}{2}(L_++L_-)+i\frac{i}{2}(L_+-L_-)=L_-$$
Which is obviously wrong. (Do note however that their matrices are correct)

Comment: How can their matrices be correct since if you do: $$L_y|l=1,m_l=1>=\frac{1}{2i}(L_+-L_-)|1,1>$$ $$=\frac{-\hbar}{\sqrt{2}i}|1,0>$$ and not  $$=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}i}|1,0>$$ as they indicate.

Comment: See http://easyspin.org/documentation/spinoperators.html for the matrices